# Connecting flask shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.10

I am new to Flask. I have started small project using python==3.10, Flask==2.3.3, flask-shell==0.1.8, flask-sqlalchemy==3.1.1.
My directory:

```
├── app
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── service
│   │   └── db
│   │       └── models.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── .flaskenv
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

**wsgi.py**

```
def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig())
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    swagger = Swagger(app)
    return app
```

**.flaskenv**

```
FLASK_APP="app/wsgi:create_app"
FLASK_ENV="development"
```

When I try to connect to flask shell

```
(.venv) dverh@LAPTOP-FUCJJ30R:/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web$ flask shell
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1063, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/dverh/spbu-practice-web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_shell.py", line 79, in shell_command
    app.env,
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'env'
```

But I can't understand what is attribute 'env' and if what I've done is right.

When i downgraded flask-shell to 0.1.3 (5 years apart), i was able to connect. I find defference between **flask_shell.py** **0.1.3**

```
from flask.globals import _app_ctx_stack
    app = _app_ctx_stack.top.app
    banner = 'Python %s on %s\nApp: %s%s\nInstance: %s' % (
        sys.version,
        sys.platform,
        app.import_name,
        app.debug and ' [debug]' or '',
        app.instance_path,
    )
```

and **flask_shell.py** **0.1.8**

```
from flask.globals import _app_ctx_stack
    app = _app_ctx_stack.top.app
    banner = 'Python %s on %s\nApp: %s%s\nInstance: %s' % (
        sys.version,
        sys.platform,
        app.import_name,
        app.env,
        app.instance_path,
    )
```

As I understood the FLASK_ENV variable gives us the possibility to control whether to allow DEBUG or not.

But then the question is why I have such an error,  because I've specified it at **.flaskenv**

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is to use flask-shell==0.1.6. It is the latest version where there is no variable `app.env`